# Rails: How can I propagate a view update from a JQuery post?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, refresh

I have a Rails controller `welcome_controller.rb` that defines an `index` and `commit` method.  The `index` method is implicitly rendering a template at `index.html.erb`, which has a `select_tag` and `button_tag`.

The `select_tag` is tied to a model indirectly.

On click `mybutton`, I have coffeescript with JQuery set to send a `post`, passing the parameters to the `commit` method in the controller.

Although the `commit` method is called, which updates the model `SomeModel` which is tied to `someselecttag`, it is not updated in the page until a browser refresh is done.  How can I display the update of `someselecttag` in the view?  I realize that I could update `someselecttag` directly from JQuery, but then it is not getting its data directly from the model itself.  What is the acceptable "Rails" way to rewrite this functionality?

Controller welcome_controller.rb

```
def index
    @somelist = SomeModel.all
end

def commit
    params.each do |param|
        SomeModel.new(param)
        SomeModel.save!
    end
    render :nothing => true
end
```

View template index.html.erb

```
<%= options = options_from_collection_for_select(@somelist, 'id', 'name') %>
<%= select_tag :someselecttag, options, multiple: true %>
<%= button_tag "do stuff", :id => "mybutton" %>
```

Coffeescript

```
$ ->
    $("#mybutton").click(->
        collection_of_stuff = somefunctionthatineededtousejqueryfor()
        $.post "/welcome/commit", collection_of_stuff
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `commit` action should return the updated copy of the model (for example as JSON). Then on ajax `success` you can take this model data and update the DOM with it.